# Set a cookie with rails and use across third party websites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, cross-domain

How does one set a cookie in rails and access this information across third party sites? For example most sites have facebook and google tracking cookies associated.

The use case is I would like to provide custom content on 3rd party apps via an API call with a user I'd from a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a cookie in one domain and access it in another. What you probably need is to embedded a script you host (usually JS, like Facebook and Google does) in the third party website, so the code setting and reading the cookie is from the same domain.